# How to echo multiple lines into files coming from a grep result

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to echo multiple lines into files coming from a grep result.

Actually, I'm `grep` some text from certain files with command:

```
find . -name *.h -o -name *.c -o -name *.cpp | xargs grep -n -l --color Apache
```

Output of above command is looks like:

```
./DIR/A.h
./DIR/B.cpp
./DIR/C.c
```

With the help of the `-l` option of grep command, I can get the file names from the grep result.

Now I want to insert multiple lines into file `A.h B.cpp C.c`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Just a quick remark: you must quote your globs in the arguments of `find`: `find . -name '*.h' -o -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp'`.

Comment: use xargs again then use sed of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the position in file where you want to insert lines. In a simplest case you could just append them to the end:

```
find . -name '*.h' -o -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp' |
xargs grep -n -l |
while read FILE; do echo -e "line1\nline2" >>"$FILE"; done
```

Here we are using `while` loop that reads each file name to `FILE` variable and append `echo` output to the end of each file.

Update: for inserting to the beggining of the files:

```
find . -name '*.h' -o -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp' |
xargs grep -n -l |
while read FILE; do (echo -e "line1\nline2"; cat "$FILE") >>"$FILE.new" && mv "$FILE.new" "$FILE"; done
```

For more advanced cases you could use `sed` that have a special commands for that (`a` and `i`).

Comment: I want to insert the lines at beginning of the files

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
find . -name *.h -o -name *.c -o -name *.cpp | \
xargs grep -n -l --color Apache | \
xargs sed -i '1s/^/text to prepend\n/'
```

This will prepend text "`text to prepend`" on every file.

Comment: Thanks, but @Slava Semushin give the first answer